# sherlockactionbar 4.4.0 error

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

Good day! I connect sherlockactionbar 4.4.0 in Eclipse. I do everything according to instructions, and get the error:

```
[2014-04-14 15:10:40 - Example] C: \ workspace \ appcompat_v7 \ res \ values ​​\ attrs.xml: 32: error: Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined 
[2014-04-14 15:10:40 - Example] C: \ workspace \ appcompat_v7 \ res \ values ​​\ attrs.xml: 33: error: Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined 
[2014-04-14 15:10:40 - Example] C: \ workspace \ appcompat_v7 \ res \ values ​​\ attrs.xml: 34: error: Attribute "windowSplitActionBar" has already been defined 
[2014-04-14 15:10:40 - Example] C: \ workspace \ appcompat_v7 \ res \ values ​​\ attrs.xml: 45: error: Attribute "actionBarTabStyle" has already been defined
```

...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp4tu.jpg

Please help!

Comment: is your project linked to `appcompat_v7` and `actionbarsherlock` at the same time ??!

Comment: Yes! If I remove actionbarsherlock, then error disappears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all :

```
C: \ workspace \ appcompat_v7 \ res \ values ​​\ attrs.xml: 32: error: Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
```

means that the resource `has already been defined`. The given path in the error message : `C: \ workspace \ appcompat_v7 \ res \ values ​​\ attrs.xml` shows that the redundancy is located there.

On another side, I don't understand why you want to use `ABSherlock` and `AppCompact` at the same time.

- If you want to use the ActionBar pattern for old devices with a `third-party library` use `ABSherlock`
- If you want to use the ActionBar pattern for old devices with the `compatibility library` use `AppCompact`

Comment: my actionbar not correctly displayed on different versions of api. wanted to try sherlock) Maybe there is another of the situation?

Comment: Yes you can try Sherlock, It's wonderful, and works nicely ! but you have to remove `appcompact` before from project libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `appcompat_v7` library out of your own project.